# can I return Action and string the same time?

Tags: c#

```
public string SendMessage(string command, Action<string> Result = null) {
  string response  = "test";
  Result(response);
  return response;
}
```

Usage:

```
string Result = SendMessage("hey");
SendMessage("hey", a => { 
   Console.WriteLine(a);
});
```

> I m getting nullreferenceexception if using `string Result = SendMessage("hey");`

edit:
do I really need to make 2 functions?

```
public string SendMessage(string command) {
  string response  = "test";
  return response;
}

public void SendMessage(string command, Action<string> Result) {
  string response  = "test";
  Result(response);
}
```

Comment: What's response variable supposed to be

Comment: You need to provide more code to cover what's going on inside SendMessage. Also, use debugger to see where its failing

Comment: the response is not the reason I edited the code take a look again

Comment: It looks like the 2nd parameter is optional, yet you are calling it every time?

Comment: I m getting nullreferenceexception because `Result = null` but If I dont make it null I cant use `string result = SendMessage..`

Comment: Why do you want to return the same `Action` that the caller passed as an argument? Wouldn't the caller have a reference to it already? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: When `SendMessage("hey")` runs, the `Result` action will be null, which is why you're getting a null reference exception. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: edited again, I want only make 1 function that can use action or just return the string

Comment: I've seen this in my code, I use ?.Invoke to add text when not null else ignore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public string SendMessage(string command, Action<string> Result = null) {
  string response  = "test";
  Result?.Invoke(response); // here
  return response;
}
```

This will fix your issue

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: does ? ignores the null?

Comment: Yes. ?. Will check if the object is null before executing next method

Comment: @schokobong, take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators for more info